# TableView is overlapping TabBar

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I have this inside of my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    title: "Portmod"

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {
            text: "Manage"
            width: implicitWidth
        }
        TabButton {
            text: "Search"
            width: implicitWidth
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        TableView {
            id: manageTab
            columnSpacing: 1
            rowSpacing: 1
            clip: true

            model: installed_pkgs_model

            selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {}

            delegate: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 300
                implicitHeight: 50
                color: selected ? "blue" : "lightgray"

                required property bool selected

                Text {
                    text: display
                }
            } 
        }
        Item {
            id: searchTab
        }
    }
}
```

It's displaying my `TableView` and `TabBar` with two `TabButton`s fine, but the `TableView` is overlapping with the `TabBar` and I have to drag the TableView out of the way to see it.

[image: TableView overlapping TabBar]

I'd like the `TableView` to be moved down so the `TabBar` is always visible, but I'm not sure how to do this. The layout system is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to move the TabBar into a [header](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#header-prop):

```
header: TabBar {
    id: bar
    width: parent.width
    TabButton {
        text: "Manage"
        width: implicitWidth
    }
    TabButton {
        text: "Search"
        width: implicitWidth
    }
}
```

Using layouts, you could do it like this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    title: "Portmod"
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        TabBar {
            id: bar
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            TabButton {
                text: "Manage"
                width: implicitWidth
            }
            TabButton {
                text: "Search"
                width: implicitWidth
            }
        }

        StackLayout {
            currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            TableView {
                id: manageTab
                columnSpacing: 1
                rowSpacing: 1
                clip: true

                model: TableModel {
                    TableModelColumn { display: "name" }
                    TableModelColumn { display: "color" }

                    rows: [
                        {
                            "name": "cat",
                            "color": "black"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "dog",
                            "color": "brown"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "bird",
                            "color": "white"
                        }
                    ]
                }

                selectionModel: ItemSelectionModel {}

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 300
                    implicitHeight: 50
                    color: selected ? "blue" : "lightgray"

                    required property bool selected
                    required property string display

                    Text {
                        text: display
                    }
                }
            }
            Item {
                id: searchTab
            }
        }
    }
}
```